# Dropdown failed after restart - discord.js

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js, interaction

This is my interaction reaction roles code.FYI i have used the new node.js so it couldnt be error because of the version. The problem is dropdown failed after restarting my bot. The "secret" at my code is the role id so just ignore it.
Here is my code:

```
client.on("message", async message => {
  if (message.content == prefix + "rr") {
  let option1 = new MessageMenuOption()
  .setLabel("Black Charcoal")
  .setValue("Option 1")
  .setDefault()
  .setEmoji("")
        
  let option2 = new MessageMenuOption()
  .setLabel("Love Magenta")
  .setValue("Option 2")
  .setDefault()
  .setEmoji("❤️")

  let selection = new MessageMenu()
  .setID("Selection")
  .setMaxValues(1)
  .setMinValues(0)
  .setPlaceholder("Select Role")
  .addOption(option1)
  .addOption(option2)

  let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
  .setColor("0x00a6ff")
  .setTitle("VIP Colour Role")
  .setDescription(`<@&secret>\n<@&secret>\n<@&secret>\n<@&secret>\n<@&secret>`)

  let menumsg = await message.channel.send(embed, selection)

const role1 = message.guild.roles.cache.find(r => r.id === "secret")
const role2 = message.guild.roles.cache.find(r => r.id === "secret")

  async function menuselection(menu) {
    switch(menu.values[0]) {
      case "Option 1": 
      if(message.member.roles.cache.has("secret")){
        await message.member.roles.add(role1)
        await message.member.roles.remove([role2])
        await menu.reply.send("Claimed Black Charcoal!", true)}
      break;
      case "Option 2":
      if(message.member.roles.cache.has("secret")){
        await message.member.roles.add(role2)
        await message.member.roles.remove([role1])
        menu.reply.send("Claimed Love Magenta!", true)}
      break;
    }
  }

  client.on("clickMenu", (menu) => {
    if(menu.message.id == menumsg.id) {
      if(menu.clicker.user.id == message.author.id) menuselection(menu)
      else menu.reply.send(":x: you are not allowed to pick something", true)
    }
  })
  }
})
```

Comment: clickMenu isn't an event

Comment: My code works successfully but after i restart my bot the interaction will not detect the older message

Comment: It's normal that when restarting the bot, it won't seek again for all the previous messages sent after he got retarted

Comment: Ahh i see, but i think we can fatch the interaction message. But idk how to fetch it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be using the now archived **discord-buttons** library. Looking through its [source code](https://github.com/discord-buttons/discord-buttons), it looks like it does not store information about which messages have menus anywhere other than the bot's memory. When you restart your bot, that information is lost, and your bot stops watching for menu clicks.

To keep it working after restarts, you would have to store such information somewhere external to your bot, like a file or some database, and start the menus again when the bot starts.

Comment: I'm still learning with javascript software, I just now i have just started learning how to make databases. I only know how to save messages to database, I didnt know how to save an interaction such as select menu and start it after restarted.